# What type of Banach spaces $X$ does the sum $x + c$ make sense where $x \in X$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: terminology, banach-spaces

What are such spaces called where we can add a constant to an element of the Banach space and the addition makes sense somehow?

Eg. in $L^2$ this always is sensible. Is there a difference to the name if $x+c \notin X$ to $x+c \in X$?

Comment: Hm, for example $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ does not have nonzero constant functions and so in fact we cannot just add $c$.  Considering instead $L^2(\Omega)$ on a bounded set, "adding a scalar" is really adding a scalar multiple of the (equiv. class of the) constant function 1.

Comment: If you mean to add a number, then a number must be an element of $X$ as a **set**. In particular, you *cannot* add it for ANY $L^2$ space, since if the space is not of finite measure, non-zero constants are not square integrable.

Comment: Yes I agree $x+c \in L^2$ if only the domain is compact. Hence my last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At face value, this never has any meaning unless $X$ is a field containing real numbers as a subfield. But, of course, as you mentioned, one can assign meaning to things like adding $c$ to a function, by defining $c$ not to be an element of $\mathbb{R}$, but an element of the set of constant functions.

This is always possible, for example, if $X$ is a Banach space which also has a unital algebra  structure (e.g. a unital Banach algebra). Then $X$ has a multiplicative unit, which we denote $1_X$, and $c := c 1_X$, in which case one can define $x + c$. This is the case in spaces such as, for example, $C(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a compact set.